# How to repeat a command, like a backreference, at the cli?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, unix-shell

What I'd like to do is run the same command twice while hitting enter once, with minimum typing.  This would be the long version for example:

```
# sudo puppet agent -tv --server foo.bar && sudo puppet agent -tv --server foo.bar
```

I thought about

```
# sudo puppet agent -tv --server foo.bar && !!
```

..but this runs the previous command (as in the last one that completed), rather than the one I've just typed.

So how do I 'backreference' my command?

Of course this could be done with a for loop or something but I'm guessing there's a more bash-ish / sort-cut-ish way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: This is a question about how I can more quickly manage the servers I administrate at work. How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

I think the bash-is way here would be either using the history or writing a loop / using variables. I don't think manipulating a not yet executed line is a possible in the way you want to do it.

Comment: But the command will have been executed by the time the second command (after the &&) runs, no?  Seems like this should be doable.

Comment: Not really you are passing a single line to the shell to be executed. The whole line appears in your history, not the two individual commands. The 'shortest' way might be something like: A='cmd' && $A && $A